# Usage of "160" instead of "156" as the UN M49 or ISO 3166-1 numeric country code for China

Tags: encoding, naming-conventions

<sub>I'm guessing the short answer is "Something complicated and political to do with Taiwan", but I'd like to know the detail...</sub>

---

I'm matching up some different international data sources and ran into a small snag because China didn't match up. One data source (some health data published by the UN agency IARC) had China as "160" (and had no entry for Taiwan in their data set) while every other source I've seen, including the official [ISO list](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search) and [UN M49 list](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/), has China as "156" (with Taiwan as "158", and "160" undefined).

For every other country, this IARC data matches the "ISO 3166-1 numeric" or "M49 UN" standard, China seems to be the only anomaly. I can't find anything explaining this alternate standard.

The only clue I can find is their ["Data Sources And Methods" page for China](http://globocan.iarc.fr/old/method/method.asp?country=160) (`country=160` in the URL...), which includes a map that depicts Taiwan as part of China.

Is 160 a lesser-used country code for "China, and Taiwan"? What's its official status?

I've tried looking on the official ISO 3166-1 pages but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: I think this should be asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.